# Setting CloudProvider after installation

Tags: kubernetes

I'm using Kubernetes on AWS, and for various reasons I needed to set up the cluster myself instead of using kube-up or kube-aws. 
This is working fine, but now I would really like to be able to create a NodePort service and have Kubernetes use ELB for external load balancing.

Is there either a way to configure my **existing** Kubernetes cluster to use the AWS CloudProvider, or to **manually** create a new cluster with the AWS CloudProvider **without** using kube-up or kube-aws?

Answer (score 1):

For RHEL7, edit the following files on the master:

- /etc/kubernetes/config

  - Add AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID and AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
- /etc/kubernetes/apiserver

  - Add '--cloud-provider=aws' to KUBE_API_ARGS variable
- controller-manager

  - Add '--cloud-provider=aws' to KUBE_CONTROLLER_MANAGER_ARGS

On minions, edit the following files:

- /etc/kubernetes/config

  - Add AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID and AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
- /etc/kubernetes/kubelet

  - Add '--cloud-provider=aws' to KUBELET_ARGS

Answer (score 0):

There are a few places where you'd need to add the `--cloud-provider=aws` flag to your existing cluster: all kubelets, the apiserver, and the controller manager. You may also need to configure IAM roles to ensure that the VMs can make successful calls to the cloud provider (check the errors logs for 403 responses).

Comment: what about the `cloud-config` file. what should be the content of that?